# file uploading gives file name undefined in Mean stack

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

i'm trying to upload imae and store it in mongoDb. so far i have defined image String attribute in nodejs model. But it gives below error.

[image]

so here is my server side controller.

**noticeController.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const  router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const notice = require('../models/notices');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination :"./public/uploads/",
    filename: (req,file,callBack) => {
        callBack(null,file.fieldname+"_"+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage : storage
}).single('image');

/add notice
router.post('/notice/add',upload,(req,res,next)=>{
    let newNotice = new notice({
        title : req.body.title,
        description : req.body.description,
        image : req.file.filename
    });

    newNotice.save((err,notice)=>{
        if(err){
            res.json({msg : 'Failed to add notice' });
        }
        else{
            res.json({ msg : 'Notice added Successfully'});
            let socketio = req.app.get('socketio');
            socketio.sockets.emit('notice.created', newNotice);
        }
    });
});

//update notice
router.put('/notice/update/:id',upload,(req,res,next)=>{
    let newNotice = new notice({
        title : req.body.title,
        description : req.body.description,
        image : req.file.filename
    });

    notice.findByIdAndUpdate({_id : req.params.id},{$set:req.body},(err,notice)=>{
        if(err){
            res.json({msg : 'Failed to update notice' });
        }
        else{
            res.json({ msg : 'Notice updated Successfully'});
        }
    });
});

module.exports =router;
```

and here is the client side ts.

**notice.component.ts**

```
  import {Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatStepper} from "@angular/material/stepper";
import {Notice} from "../../shared/models/notice";
import {NoticeService} from "../../core/services/notice.service";
import {SnackBarComponent} from "../../shared/popup-modals/snack-bar/snack-bar.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notice',
  templateUrl: './notice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notice.component.css'],
  providers : [NoticeService]
})
export class NoticeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('objectId') selectedObjectId : string;

  public imageString: String;
  isEdit : boolean = false;
socket;
  uploading: boolean = false;
  notice: Notice = {
    title: '',
    description:'',
    image:''
  };
  notices: Notice[];
  finalNoticeList: Notice[] = [];
  noticeForm = new FormGroup({
    image: new FormControl(),
    title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),

  });

  constructor(private noticeService: NoticeService, private customPopup : SnackBarComponent) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getNoticeList();
   
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log("check "+ this.selectedObjectId);
    this.getNotice(this.selectedObjectId);
    this.noticeForm.disable();


  }

  deleteNotice(id: any) {

    this.noticeService.deleteNotice(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.getNoticeList();
    });
  }

  addNotice(){
    let newNotice = new Notice();
    newNotice.title = this.noticeForm.controls.title.value;
    newNotice.description = this.noticeForm.controls.description.value;
    newNotice.image = this.noticeForm.controls.image.value;
    if(this.isEdit){
      this.noticeService.updateNotice(this.selectedObjectId,newNotice).subscribe(notice=>{
        this.customPopup.openSnackBar("Notice Updated Successfully!","warning")
        this.getNoticeList();
      },error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      this.isEdit = false;
    }
    else{
      this.noticeService.addNotices(newNotice).subscribe(notice=>{
        this.customPopup.openSnackBar("Notice Saved Successfully!","success")
        this.getNoticeList();
      },error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    this.noticeForm.disable();

  }

  setToEdit(){
    this.noticeForm.enable();
    this.isEdit =true;
  }


  setFormData(){
    console.log("title "+ this.notice.title);
    this.noticeForm.controls.title.setValue(this.notice.title);
    this.noticeForm.controls.description.setValue(this.notice.description);
  }

  getNoticeList() {
    this.noticeService.getNotices()
      .subscribe(notices => {
        this.notices = notices;
        this.finalNoticeList = notices;
      });
  }

  getNotice(id:string){
    this.noticeService.getNotice(id)
      .subscribe(notice => {
        this.noticeForm.controls.title.setValue(notice.title);
        this.noticeForm.controls.description.setValue(notice.description);
      });

  }


  setState(){
    this.noticeForm.disable();
    this.isEdit = false;
  }



}
```

**html part**

```
<input  type='file' formControlName="image" id="image"  />
```

I'm using mutler package. I search thruogh google for an answe. But I couldn't find it. So where did I do wrong?

Comment: paste your whole notice.component.ts code

Comment: question updated

Comment: Please console 'req.file' in 
add notice router.

Answer (score 0):

The provided `name` attribute in your html must match the `string` you pass to the multer call. So you should change your html to:

```
<input type='file' formControlName="image" name="image" id="image" />
```